# Continuity of $f(x) = \frac 1 x - \frac 1 {x+1} + \frac{1}{x+2} - \cdots$

Tags: real-analysis

> Is function 
>   $$f(x) = \frac 1 x  - \frac 1 {x+1} + \frac{1}{x+2} - \frac 1{x+3} + \cdots$$
>   continuous on $(0, \infty)$ ?

I think I should extend the continuity of each term to $f$ but I cannot show that series converges uniformly.

Comment: Can you perhaps show that the sequence of partial sums is uniformly Cauchy on $(0,\infty)$?

Comment: @VáclavMordvinov thanks I will try. Most likely it will work :)

Comment: It is a general fact that every rational function (quotient of two polynomials) that does avoid the zeros of the denominator is continuous. So you can probably look up this result in some textbook?

Comment: @James Yup but I need to extend it to infinite series. If it were finite, things would have been lot easier.

Comment: I see, didn't take this into account. Then I agree, that the answer of @VáclavMordvinov should be the right thing to do ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$$\left( \frac 1 x - \frac 1 {x+1} \right) + \left( \frac 1 {x+2} - \frac 1 {x+3} \right) + \cdots + \left( \frac 1 {x+2n} -\frac 1 {x+2n-1} \right)$$ $$=\frac 1 {x(x+1)}+\frac 1 {(x+2)(x+3)}+\cdots +\frac 1 {(x+2n) (x+2n+1)}$$ $$\leq \frac 1 {x(x+1)}+\frac 1 {2^{2}}+ \frac 1 {4^{2}}+\cdots+\frac 1 {(2n)^{2}} $$.

This gives uniform convergence of the partial sums.

Answer (score 3):

How to prove this function is continuous:

1. Show the sequence of partial sums is uniformly Cauchy on $(0,\infty)$.
2. Conclude the sequence of partial sums is uniformly convergent on $(0,\infty)$.
3. Conclude the sequence of partial sums is continuous on $(0,\infty)$.